# What is the insertion format of DATE in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below code gives error:

> "ORA-01821: date format not recognized"

But why??

---

```
INSERT INTO SALES_ORDER_C_B1_027 (ORDER_NO,ORDER_DATE,CLIENT_NO,DELYTYPE,BILLYN,SALESMAN_NO,DELYDATE,ORDER_STATUS)
    VALUES('O19001',TO_DATE('12-JAN-96','DD-MMM-YY'),'C00001','F','N','S00001',TO_DATE('20-JAN-96' ,'DD-MMM-YY'),'IN PROCESS');
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_ORDER_C_B1_027
(
    ORDER_NO VARCHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY,
    CLIENT_NO VARCHAR(6),
    ORDER_DATE DATE,
    DELYADDR VARCHAR(25),
    SALESMAN_NO VARCHAR(6),
    DELYTYPE CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'F',
    BILLYN CHAR(1),
    DELYDATE DATE, 
    ORDER_STATUS VARCHAR(10),
    CHECK(ORDER_NO LIKE 'O%'),
    CHECK(DELYTYPE IN('P','F')),
    CHECK(DELYDATE>ORDER_DATE),
    CHECK(ORDER_STATUS IN('IN PROCESS','FULFILLED','BACK ORDER','CANCELLED')),
    FOREIGN KEY (CLIENT_NO) REFERENCES CLIENT_MASTER_C_B1_027(CLIENT_NO),
    FOREIGN KEY (SALESMAN_NO) REFERENCES SALESMAN_MASTER_C_B1_027(SALESMAN_NO)
);
```

Comment: Check your NLS settings or use a date format that is language independent e.g. DD-MM-YYYY and it's about time to start using 4-digit years :-)

Comment: In answer to your question title, there is no "format" when inserting a date, it just needs to be a valid date. (What is the insertion format for `NUMBER`?) Also, those `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` columns should all be `VARCHAR2`, which is the standard string type in Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct reason of ORA-1821 is wrong date format: for value `12-JAN-96` mask should be `DD-MON-YY`, not `DD-MMM-YY`.

After that your statement will work, but it contains two other errors. First of all, I doubt if you mentioned year 2096, so you should use four-digits format instead of two-digits. Next, it would work with one NLS settings and fail with others depends of date language.

That's why the best decision in your case is to use date literals and write date value as `DATE '1996-01-12'` without any to_date's

Answer (score 2):

`MMM` is the problem.  You want `MON`.  However, I would use the `DATE` keyword:

```
VALUES('O19001', DATE '1996-01-12','C00001', 'F', 'N', 'S00001', DATE '1996-01-20', 'IN PROCESS');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `'DD-MON-RR'` or `'DD-MM-RRRR'` instead of `'DD-MMM-YY'`, as date format.
you'd better to use date format with `rr` instead of `yy`, in your case. This format is related to year 2k(millenium) problem. As example, when you enter `96`, you get `1996`(the second part of the century"year between `50-99`"), and when you enter `05` you get `2005`(the second part of the century"year between `00-49`")

Comment: @AkashRc sorry, in a rush i made mistake. Now, it'ok .

Comment: In "DD-MON-YY", It takes year as 2096 while I want 1996, but thanks ,your answer helped me :)

Comment: @AkashRc in that case , you'd better to use date format with `rr` instead of `yy`.